# Is it OK to propose package modifications or improvements?

Tags: discussion, packages

The title says it all: I wanted to share my desire to see one day the features of `cleveref` and `varioref` all in one package.

However, this is not a real question. Is it OK to post it on TeX.SE?

Or -better- how can it be phrased so that it's not marked as "not a real question"?

Comment: It's always a matter of taste, what might be considered an 'improvement'. I would not use a question for this but contact the maintainer(s) of the packages.

Comment: Regardless of the answer to this question, it’s great that you asked here first – thanks! (+1)

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think I should take credit for properly using tex.stackexchange and meta.tex.stackexchange :)

Comment: But you could ask: how can I achieve such-and-such? where such-and-such is a combination of features from the 2 packages. For example, you could show that you know how to achieve feature 1 (use package 1) and feature 2 (use package 2) but that you would like to know how to achieve features 1+2 together. Of course, that might yield answers you don't expect (e.g. use package 3) but I'm assuming that it is the combination of features you really want, regardless of implementation (within reason).

Comment: Note that `fancyref` has some features of both packages but I've no idea if it has the ones you want from `cleveref`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it is not ok, surely not in a question. Remember that StackExchange is not a forum, questions have to be questions, and even beyond, have to be objective, one question per question etc. Package patch proposal doesn't sound like a question.

It is, however, ok to propose a patch to an existing package, but only in an answer. I believe that the maintainer of the package should be notified, so that they either accept or reject the patch.

If you have a patch proposal, just contact the package maintainer. TeX.SE is not a place for doing this, nor for open-ended discussions about such proposals.